# Как найти контекст в addEventListener

Tags: javascript, dom

Есть три элемента на которые пытаюсь повесить обработчик событий. Соответственно, при обращении к ф-ии handleScrollGallery(event) контекст теряется и в this только window. Подскажите, как указать на конкретный элемен, с которым взаимодействую? Почему-то не могу справиться с bind

```
function handleScrollGallery(event) {
    console.log(this)
}

Array.from(gallerySliders).forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener('wheel', (evt) => {
        handleScrollGallery(evt)
    })
})
```

Comment: Не стрелочная функция `addEventListener('wheel', function (evt){})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
item.addEventListener('wheel', handleScrollGallery);
```

---

```
item.addEventListener('wheel', function(evt) {
    handleScrollGallery.call(this, evt);
})
```

---

```
item.addEventListener('wheel', (evt) => {
    handleScrollGallery.call(evt.target, evt);
})
```

---

```
item.addEventListener('wheel', (evt) => {
    handleScrollGallery.bind(item)(evt);
})
```

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!

Comment: @elarri Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.